# Securing controller action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In ASP.NET MVC 2, to secure controller action, i have created a class `RequirePermission` inherited from `ActionFilterAttribute` class. The controller action looks like

```
[RequirePermission(permissions="CanView")]

    public ActionResult List()
    {
       ...
    }
```

I have an enum with name `Permissions`

```
public enum Permissions { CanDoEdit, CanView, CanInsert }
```

The `RequirePermission` class looks like

```
public class RequirePermission : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string permissions;
        string[] param = { "," };
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            string[] requirePermissions = permissions.Split(param, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


           if (requirePermissions.Contains(Permissions.CanDoEdit.ToString()))
           {
                     //Check permission 
           }
           if (requirePermissions.Contains(Permissions.CanView.ToString()))
           {
                     //Check permission 
           }
           if (requirePermissions.Contains(Permissions.CanInsert.ToString()))
           {
                    //Check permission 
           }
        }
    }
```

Now instead of making different attributes , I want to use `RequirePermission` attribute like
`[RequirePermission(permissions=Permissions.CanView+","+Permissions.CanEdit)]` so that i can use it for different scenerious. but the compiler throw the following error.

*An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
[Flags]
public enum Permissions 
{ 
    CanDoEdit = 1 << 0, 
    CanView = 1 << 1,
    CanInsert = 1 << 2
}
```

And then:

```
[RequirePermission(permissions = Permissions.CanView & Permissions.CanEdit)]
```

And finally to verify that CanView is set:

```
if ((requirePermissions & Permissions.CanView) == Permissions.CanView)
{
    // The user has CanView permission
}
```

Comment: Actually I made a mistake by using `Permissions.CanView | Permissions.CanEdit`. I think it should be `Permissions.CanView & Permissions.CanEdit` to express that a user has both permissions.

Comment: i think you are wrong. To set both permissions, use 
Permissions.CanView | Permissions.CanEdit. 
But to avoid overwriting the enum values, i have set the values in pover of 2.